# Bluetooth identifier on iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, uuid

[image]

See the image above. I am pairing my iOS app from iphone1  to a single Bluetooth device, say BT1, which is further inter-connected with other similar bluetooth devices via Bluetooth Mesh. As soon as I connect with BT1, I get a uuid1 for the connection.

Now, I need to uniquely identify the **paired** device uuid. This is essential as I would like to transfer my phone app settings to another iPhone, say iPhone2, via cloud, so that any phone can connect to the original paired BT device. But when I try to pair iPhone2 to Device1, I get a different uuid2 for Device1, because of which, I cannot match it with the uuid1. So if uuid1 = uuid2, then the cloud will send me the original settings.

Question - 
1. is it technically possible to ensure that a bluetooth device shares the same uuid to all its client?
2. If #1 is no, is there an alternative?

Thanks in adv.

Comment: Are you getting the device UUID from the `CBPeripheral.identifier`?

Comment: You will need to add a characteristic to your Bluetooth device that provides a unique identifier. That way a phone can connect to the device, read that characteristic and get the unique identifier for the device. Core Bluetooth does not provide access to the device MAC and the identifier returned by Core Bluetooth is not portable across devices.

Comment: Is it possible to get the macID of the bluetooth device in my iOS app?